# Whether to use independence assumption or union bound for lower bounding probability

Tags: probability

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be i.i.d random variables. Let the sample space be $\Omega$ for each $z_i, i=1,2$. For simplicity, let these random variables be identity maps from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $P_{z_1}(\{z_1 \in A_1\}) \geq c_1$ and $P_{z_2}(\{z_2 \in A_2\}) \geq c_2$.

I want to lower bound $P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\} \cap\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\})$ where $A_1' = A_1\times\Omega$ and $A_2' = \Omega\times A_2$ and $A_1$ and $A_2$ were defined earlier.

My question is whether both approaches (using the i.i.d assumption or using union bound) are correct? Am I making any mistake from going from set $A_1$ to set $A_1'$?

---

#### My attempts:

Because $z_1$ and $z_2$ are i.i.d, I can use $P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\} \cap\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\})= P_{z_1}(\{z_1 \in A_1\})\cdot P(\{z_2 \in A_2\}) \geq c_1\cdot c_2$ as the lower bound.

I also think, one can ignore the independence assumption and use union bound (or Boole's identity) as follows:
\begin{align}
P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\} \cap\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\}) &= 1 - P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\}^{c} \cup\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\}^{c})\\
&\geq 1 - \left(P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\}^{c}) + P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\}^{c})\right)\\
&= 1 - \left( 1 - P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\}) + 1 - P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\})\right)\\
&=-1 + P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_1'\}) + P_{z_1,z_2}(\{(z_1,z_2) \in A_2'\})\\
&\geq -1 + c_1 + c_2
\end{align}

Comment: The two sentences in the first paragraph are contradictory. The first one states that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are independent random variables, the second one that $z_1=z_2$ almost surely. Unless the random variables $z_i$ are almost surely constant, this is impossible.

Comment: Sure, as is necessary to declare that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are independent. Then the second sentence seems absurd for the reason explained in my previous comment.

Comment: ?? Quote: "for each $i=1,2$, let the element $\omega \in \Omega$ be the same as $z_i$ (i.e., $z_i(\omega) = \omega$)." Hence... $z_1(\omega)=\omega=z_2(\omega)$ for every $\omega$.

Comment: I am saying $z_i$ are identity maps. That is, $z_i(\omega) = \omega$. I did  not want to say $z_1(\omega) = z_2(\omega)$. My motivation for using this identity map was to avoid some notation. Lets say $\Omega = {1,..,6}$ and $z_i(\omega) = \omega$. Does that mean, $P_{z_1,z_2}(\{z_1(\omega) = z_2(\omega)\}) = 1$?

Comment: Sorry but if $z_i(\omega)=\omega$ for $i=1$ and for $i=2$ then $z_1=z_2$ **always**. Unless you explain this point, I am afraid there is no question here.

Comment: No, because I have no idea about the setting you have in mind. If your goal is to say that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are i.i.d., just say that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are i.i.d. // Re your question if this is indeed the question you intended, note that $c_1c_2\gt-1+c_1+c_2$ in full generality hence (unsurprisingly) the lower bound using the independence hypothesis is better than the lower bound not using it.